# Method of isoclines

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have this exercise and I do not know how to solve it.

> By using the method of isoclines represent the integrals of equation corbes nonautonomous $x'=x^2-t$.

There are some indications: Let $P = I_0$, the parabola $x^2 = t$. Show that $P^-$ is a trapping region ($P = P^+\cup P^-$).

How can we prove it?

Comment: Please let me know if I have changed the meaning of your question during my edit.

Comment: no no thank you .

Comment: please help me ,i need help

Comment: @Jasper Loy: what does this question have to do with graded modules (dynamical systems seems to be a perfectly appropriate tag) and why did you remove the pleasantries? The former seems to be a mistake and the latter a rather impolite thing to do.

Comment: Hi, please have you any idea to solve this exercise ?

Comment: No idea ???????

Comment: What's $I_0$? What are $P^+$ and $P^-$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve $t=x^2$ divides the $t$-$x$ plane into three distinct regions:

1. on the parabola, $t=x^2$ so $x'(t)=0$ and thus solutions of the DE are flat
2. inside the parabola, $x^2<t$ so $x'(t)<0$ and thus solutions are decreasing in $t$
3. outside the parabola, $x^2>t$ so $x'(t)>0$ and thus solutions are increasing in $t$

as this plot demonstrates:

[image: Mathematica graphics]